# return value type auto deduction in static member function fails

Tags: c++, c++14, auto

I have this code

```
struct Foo {

    static constexpr auto get() { return static_cast<int>(3); }

    Foo(int t = get()) {}
};

int main() {
    Foo t;
}
```

That fails to compile with clang++ with the following error

```
test.cpp:7:17: error: function 'get' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
    Foo(int t = get()) {}
                ^
test.cpp:5:27: note: 'get' declared here
    static constexpr auto get() { return static_cast<int>(3); }
                          ^
1 error generated.
```

The error looks like [Use of 'auto func(int)' before deduction of 'auto' in C++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514665/use-of-auto-funcint-before-deduction-of-auto-in-c14/43514762) but in my case, the function is defined before... Moving the function as is outside the class allows successful compilation (which is strange to me because I don't really see the difference).

I tried with Gcc and it complains too.

Why would the use of `auto` here be illformed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267213/compiler-cant-deduce-the-return-type/49267325#49267325

Comment: ok thank you for the link, I'll mark my question as duplicate

Comment: But default function argument is also a complete-class context, it should also be parsed after the class definition is parsed, like function body :/